# Boolean Algebra: How do I implenent a 4 bit signed comparator

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I'm studying for my digital electronics exam and I'm a bit lost here.

The goal of the exercise was to build 2 4bit comparators out of single bit comparators, one using unsigned bits and the other with signed bits.

This is the equation for the unsigned circuit:

A>B, Xout: (a xor b)'Yin 
A=B, Yin: ab' + Xin 
A<B, Zout: a'b + Zin

I was able to draw the unsigned circuit, but I'm struggling to understand how to obtain the boolean equations for the signed version.

I searched everywhere and I only found the unsigned implementation.

This is how I draw the 1bit block of the unsigned version:
[image]

Comment: Can you think of a way to "map" the signed integers onto the unsigned integers, preserving their order? (It's actually remarkably simple.)

Comment: I thought about mapping but I don't see how this can work for all situations, if I map both inputs I may end up with a: 1010->0110, b: 1111->0001, result: -6 bigger than -1, if i map only the negative input I will end up with -1 = 1 or -4 = 4, and not -1<1, if i only map the positive input and do a= 1111 (-1) and b= 0111 (7), maping 7 would result in 1010, 1111>1010 so i really don't know which integer i should map for a given input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's list all of the 4-bit 2's-complement numbers from smallest to largest, and also list all of the 4-bit unsigned numbers from smallest to largest. You know how to compare the unsigned numbers. Can you see a simple way to convert (map) the 2's-complement numbers to unsigned numbers, preserving the sort order?

```
2's complement  unsigned
==============  ========
      -8  1000  0000   0  (smallest)
      -7  1001  0001   1
      -6  1010  0010   2
      -5  1011  0011   3
      -4  1100  0100   4
      -3  1101  0101   5
      -2  1110  0110   6
      -1  1111  0111   7
       0  0000  1000   8
       1  0001  1001   9
       2  0010  1010  10
       3  0011  1011  11
       4  0100  1100  12
       5  0101  1101  13
       6  0110  1110  14
       7  0111  1111  15  (largest)
```

Comment: Oh, now I see it! I didn't fully understand what you meant by "map", I thought you were talking about converting, so this is as simple as toggling the MSB, thank you so much!